# How remove parent style with css?

Tags: css, tabs

I have tabs and I want to remove style "border-bottom" of parent element when tab is active. How I can do it? My Code:

```css
.content .tabs .tab {
 border: 1px solid #838c96;
 border-right: 0;
 z-index: 5;
}

.content .tabs .tab:first-child {
 border-right: 0;
}

.content .tabs .tab:last-of-type {
 border-right: 1px solid #838c96;
}

.content .tabs .tab a {
 color: #242221;
}

.content .tab .tab a.active:has(< .tab) {
 border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
 <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1">Панели</a></li>
 <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">Столбы</a></li>
 <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Т. характеристики</a></li>
 <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Инструкции</a></li>
 <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test5">Сертификаты</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ0Mq.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. CSS has no parent selector. I'd suggest you either toggle `.active` on the `<li>` in stead, or apply all your styles to `<a>`.

Comment: `CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets` so you can style the HTML from top to bottom ( parent > child ) not the other way around. you can style the parent depending on it's child using JQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets so you can style the HTML from top to bottom ( parent > child ) not the other way around. you can style the parent depending on it's child using JQ

for example something like this :

```js
$("li.tab a").each(function(){
if($(this).hasClass("active")){
    $(this).parent().addClass("noborder")
}
});
```

```css
.content .tabs .tab {
 border: 1px solid #838c96;
 border-right: 0;
 z-index: 5;
}

.content .tabs .tab:first-child {
 border-right: 0;
}

.content .tabs .tab:last-of-type {
 border-right: 1px solid #838c96;
}

.content .tabs .tab a {
 color: #242221;
}

.content ul li.tab.noborder{
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">


<ul class="tabs">
 <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1">Панели</a></li>
 <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">Столбы</a></li>
 <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Т. характеристики</a></li>
 <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Инструкции</a></li>
 <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test5">Сертификаты</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

add a class `noborder` to the `li` that has a child `a` with class `active`. then, in CSS, add `border:none` to that `li.noborder`